# Why is the last page of Word document not deleting?

Tags: microsoft-word

Here is one of my MS-Word documents which has a blank last page. I tried everything but that stubborn page is not deleting.

[Here is the link of MS-Word page to download.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zndw6mmjwd9evx2/Agenda%20PFL.docx?dl=0)

Can anyone help me and let me know what is happening with this last page?

Comment: Go to the end of the document and press the backspace key until you get to the page before. This always works for me.

Comment: No, it didn't work... Please download the word file from the given link and please try.

Comment: I cannot. It will not let me.

Comment: @John You have to login to Dropbox to download the page

Comment: You may want to look at Deleting "Blank" Pages by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BlankPage.htm

Comment: refer to this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-a-blank-page-a5efa26e-6a21-4ac8-81ce-220a46d105a8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is actually pretty easy.  You have a section break after the words "Conduct Your Family Wealth Legacy Interview."  The section after the section break is set to start as a new page.  Change the layout for this section to "Continuous" and the new page will disappear instantly.  See attached image.[image: Section layout changed to "Continuous"]